# How do I call SetWindowLong() in the 64-bit versions of Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, setwindowlong

In the header file `WinUser.h`, there is a part in which the constants of the second parameter of [`SetWindowLong()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926164.aspx) are defined.

```
// ...

#define GWL_WNDPROC         (-4)
#define GWL_HINSTANCE       (-6)
#define GWL_HWNDPARENT      (-8)
#define GWL_STYLE           (-16)
#define GWL_EXSTYLE         (-20)
#define GWL_USERDATA        (-21)
#define GWL_ID              (-12)

#ifdef _WIN64

#undef GWL_WNDPROC
#undef GWL_HINSTANCE
#undef GWL_HWNDPARENT
#undef GWL_USERDATA

#endif /* _WIN64 */

#define GWLP_WNDPROC        (-4)
#define GWLP_HINSTANCE      (-6)
#define GWLP_HWNDPARENT     (-8)
#define GWLP_USERDATA       (-21)
#define GWLP_ID             (-12)

// ...
```

But they are right after undefined if `_WIN64` is defined; and it is defined in my 64-bit system.

As you see, there is also a `GWLP_***` set of constants, but they are not documented in the page of `SetWindowLong()`.

Why are these constants undefined in x64 systems?
What is the alternative way of calling `SetWindowLong()` in x64 systems?

---

My system:
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
IDE: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Update 3

Comment: Right at the top of the documentation is *Note  This function has been superseded by the SetWindowLongPtr function. To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use the SetWindowLongPtr function.*

Comment: @chir I can't find that note in the documentation page I gave in my question.

Comment: I guess the mobile version of the documentation doesn't include the note.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Some of the window data values (the ones that refer to "pointer sized" objects like the window procedure, for example) need to be 64 bit in an x64 build. The old `SetWindowLong()` and `GetWindowLong()` functions are limited to `DWORD` sized (32 bit) values for backwards compatibility, and Microsoft have introduced new versions, `SetWindowLongPtr()` and `GetWindowLongPtr()` that allow you to work with pointer-sized values (32 bit in a 32 bit build, and 64 bit in a 64 bit build).

These days it is recommended that you always use `SetWindowLongPtr()` and the `GWLP_xxx` constants, whether you are building for 32 or 64 bit, but in a 64 bit build you **need** to use the new functions and so the defines are #undefined to cause build errors that force you to fix your code.

Comment: I hit this issue and this answer helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Is it harmless to use GetWindowLong/SetWindowLong on GWL_STYLE and GWL_EXSTYLE since those never exceed 32 bits of data?

Comment: @William Yes that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you're NOT defining the following:

`#define NOWINOFFSETS`

which disables `GWL_*`, `GCL_*`, ie. `GetWindowLongPtr` and family, as well as associated routines.

Answer (score 2):

```
    As specified in <WinUser.h>
    //If config is _WIN64 then use new versioned macro

    #define GWLP_WNDPROC        (-4)
    #define GWLP_HINSTANCE      (-6)
    #define GWLP_HWNDPARENT     (-8)
    #define GWLP_USERDATA       (-21)
    #define GWLP_ID             (-12)

    //else for _WIN32

    #undef GWL_WNDPROC
    #undef GWL_HINSTANCE
    #undef GWL_HWNDPARENT
    #undef GWL_USERDATA
```