# Error message "GWL_WNDPROC undeclared" while following this tutorial

Tags: c, winapi

I am following this tutorial:
*[theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html)*

In section 4 (message looping) (*[Understanding the Message Loop](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html)*), there is the code:

```
WNDPROC fWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(Msg.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
fWndProc(Msg.hwnd, Msg.message, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
```

I tried to compile it, but I got this error message:

> GWL_WNDPROC undeclared

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: That seems rather unlikely, if you properly #included windows.h  Be sure to tell us if you got more than 1 error, the first 4 are the important ones.

Comment: This is a question that requires a [mcve], together with a verbatim report of the compiler errors.

Comment: `GWL_WNDPROC` is really undeclared. need use `GWLP_WNDPROC`

Comment: @HansPassant: It literally takes less than a minute to look inside *WinUser.h*, and verify, that your statement is blatantly wrong. With currently 2 upvotes, it's probably wise to just purge that comment.

Comment: Hmm, it could just as well be blatantly right.  Just flag it if you can't live with it.

Comment: The reason for this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178628/how-do-i-call-setwindowlong-in-the-64-bit-versions-of-windows/18178661#18178661).

Answer (score 24):

In `<WinUser.h>`, the following declarations exist:

```
/*
 * Window field offsets for GetWindowLong()
 */
#define GWL_WNDPROC         (-4)
...

#ifdef _WIN64

#undef GWL_WNDPROC
#undef GWL_HINSTANCE
#undef GWL_HWNDPARENT
#undef GWL_USERDATA

#endif /* _WIN64 */

#define GWLP_WNDPROC        (-4)
```

In case `_WIN64` is defined (your target is 64 bit), the `GWL_WNDPROC` is really undefined. You need use `GWLP_WNDPROC` instead.

Also with `GWLP_WNDPROC`, you need use `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr`, but not `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong`.